# Error MikTex with Texstudio

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio

I'm trying to compile a stnaderd document that was fine until yesterday, now I've opened the file and when I try to compile it this message occurs:

```
Unfortunately, the package latex-tools could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

and this is the log file:

```
2021-01-25 16:42:10,917+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18884) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode PhD_Thesis.tex
2021-01-25 16:42:10,926+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-01-25 16:42:13,135+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package latex-tools triggered by tex/latex/latex-tools\indentfirst.sty
2021-01-25 16:42:13,135+0100 INFO  pdflatex.core - turning on administrator mode
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: hr="0x800401e4"
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstallerImpl.cpp:1291
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: hr="0x800401e4"
2021-01-25 16:42:13,180+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstallerImpl.cpp
2021-01-25 16:42:13,181+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1291
2021-01-25 16:42:13,183+0100 INFO  pdflatex.core - turning off administrator mode
2021-01-25 16:42:14,030+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (18884) finishes with exit code 1
2021-01-25 16:42:14,032+0100 WARN  miktex.core - still open: PhD_Thesis.tex
```

EDIT:

now every time I try to compile something this message is shown:

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/matte/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you ne
ed help.

and this is the log file:

```
2021-01-25 18:53:44,061+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
```

2021-01-25 18:53:49,112+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-01-25 18:53:52,257+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-25 18:53:52,257+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-01-25 18:53:52,257+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-25 18:53:52,257+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 649
2021-01-25 18:54:19,077+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2021-01-25 18:54:23,961+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-01-25 18:54:27,470+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-25 18:54:27,470+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-01-25 18:54:27,470+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-25 18:54:27,470+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 649
2021-01-25 18:55:37,251+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2021-01-25 18:55:41,911+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-01-25 18:55:44,975+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-25 18:55:44,975+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-01-25 18:55:44,975+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-25 18:55:44,975+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 649
2021-01-25 18:56:13,083+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2021-01-25 18:56:17,743+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-01-25 18:56:20,854+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-25 18:56:20,854+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-01-25 18:56:20,854+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-25 18:56:20,854+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 649

Comment: try to install latex-tools directly with the miktex console.

Comment: it was unable to find it

Comment: now every time I try to compyle a document this message is shown:
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/matte/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX p
roject page, if you need help.

Comment: look without a clue what the error is, nobody can help you. So check this log ...

Comment: Yes sorry, just updated

Comment: Search for the log-file of the last format creation (it should be in `....\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex`) and show its content.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem (see [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/695)).

Comment: unfortunately did not solve the problem:(

Comment: @ChristianSchenk that could be one part of the problem. But the `The memory dump file could not be found` could be related to another problem which I saw now the second time: for some reason UnicodeData.txt is not found. E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580274/2388

Comment: I've solved by re-installing MikTex and TeXstudio in the secondary hard drive.